# HTML loading before CSS in Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My [Site's](http://www.campfireinc.org/) Html is loading before the CSS in Firefox for a split second. Is it because i am using @import?

I am using the [Foundation 3 Wordpress theme with a child theme](http://320press.com/wp-foundation/).

Thanks for your help.

```
@import url("../wp-foundation/style.css");

@import url("css/nav.css");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES!

> When @import is used, the browser is unable to download the
>   stylesheets in parallel and add delays during the loading of a web
>   page. @import in IE behaves like a  at the bottom of the page.

[[1]](http://www.quora.com/Cascading-Style-Sheets/Why-is-the-import-CSS-method-so-slow)

So link to it directly.

Comment: Thank You! I will link directly.